# Why do I receive "Could not load the assembly" when hosting with GoDaddy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I received the error "Could not load the assembly `App_Web_h0gd1d04`" when hosting my site with GoDady.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_h0gd1d04'.
>   Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true"
>   inherits="_Default, App_Web_h0gd1d04" %> Line 2:  <%@ Register
>   assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
>   tagprefix="cc1" %> Line 3:
>
> Source File: /Educationpublish/default.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Please Help me ..

Comment: which version of ajaxtoolkit are you using??  is ajaxtoolkit dll in /Bin folder??

Answer (score 0):

Clear out your /bin directory on GoDaddy.  Re-build and publish your application.  Your generated assembly references appear to be out of sync.

Comment: Then make sure your app pool is recycled, otherwise it's your code not a build and deploy issue.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours and days on this, here is what worked for me:

1. On Plesk hosting with godaddy, set your .net runtime version to 3.5.
2. Add a `<trust>` element in your web.config with level set to full as seen below.

Notes: This does not work on classic windows hosting with godaddy as you're forbidden to run under full trust in that environment. Plesk hosting allows full trust.

If you try to run Ajax Control Toolkit on Plesk, under 4+ .net runtime version, you will receive 500 errors which you may have problems getting details for.

```xml
<configuration>
<system.web>
<trust level="Full" />
</system.web>

</configuration>
```